# Can Jodd provide functionality like apache tiles framework?

Tags: java, jodd

I am using jodd in my project. I am using lots of functionality jodd like madvoc , petite. I am looking functionality like apache tiles framework I have seen and read the post http://jodd.org/doc/decora/ but I don't get to much. Can any one provide working example of decora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is not short question - so please be a bit more concrete here on StackOverflow :)

[Decora](http://jodd.org/doc/decora/) is quite simple and somewhat different then Apache Tiles. It reminds on old, good SiteMesh. Now, let me explain how it works:

- with your business logic, create an design-free html page. Generate the content right in the `<body>`.
- Now, create a template with design, colors, images... Choose where you want your content to be injected; like inside certain `div`.
- After you apply Decora, the `body` content from the page will be decorated with the template, by inserting it into this `div`.

This is how it works in a nutshell. You have working example in [Uphea](http://jodd.org/uphea/) but just note that is a bit older version of Jodd used. Also, there is [quickstart project](https://github.com/oblac/jodd-quickstart/tree/master/webapp1), that has Decora configured.

Decora is more powerful then above - you may have more regions on one page, set the header tags like `title` and so on. You may use html tags for marking the regions, or JSP tags, etc.